# one UIViewController and multiple UIViews each

Tags: iphone, ipad

I want to have one iPad screen with multiple independent sections that can be dragged by the users finger.

Each section will have different objects like UIButton, UILabel, UIImage, etc. When the section is dragged, all of the associated objects in that section will moved with it as a group.

Therefore I was thinking each section could be a UIView or a UIViewController.

The whole thing should be under one UIViewController type (navigation etc).

I been trying different things but nothing works fully, only pieces of it works. I tried using different UIViews, and loading nibs into that, but then the buttons don't respond to touches.

Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As per Apple's Review Policy:

https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html

> Apps that create alternate
>   desktop/home screen environments or
>   simulate multi-app widget experiences
>   will be rejected.

I would recommend rethinking your design (not trying to be rude !!)